# Не работает js функция. Почему не переварачиваются карточки? Как можно прописать функцию, чтобы при нажатии появлялись иконки?

Tags: javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const app = {
    cards: [
      //  A list that holds all cards
      {
        name: 'diamond',
        icon: 'fa fa-diamond',
        class: 'card'
      },
      {
        name: 'diamond',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-diamond'
      },
      {
        name: 'plane',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-paper-plane-o'
      },
      {
        name: 'plane',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-paper-plane-o'
      },
      {
        name: 'anchor',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-anchor'
      },
      {
        name: 'anchor',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-anchor'
      },
      {
        name: 'bolt',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-bolt'
      },
      {
        name: 'bolt',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-bolt'
      },
      {
        name: 'cube',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-cube'
      },
      {
        name: 'cube',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-cube'
      },
      {
        name: 'leaf',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-leaf'
      },
      {
        name: 'leaf',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-leaf'
      },
      {
        name: 'bicycle',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-bicycle'
      },
      {
        name: 'bicycle',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-bicycle'
      },
      {
        name: 'bomb',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-bomb'
      },
    ],
    init: function() {
      app.shuffle();
    },

    shuffle: function() {
      let random = 0;
      let temp = 0;
      for (i = 1; i < app.cards.length; i++) {
        random = Math.round(Math.random() * i);
        temp = app.cards[i];
        app.cards[i] = app.cards[random];
        app.cards[random] = temp;
      }
      app.assignCards();

    },
    assignCards: function() {
      $('.card').each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr('data-card-value', app.cards[index]);
        app.cards[index];
      });
      app.clickHandlers();
    },

    clickHandlers: function() {
      $('.card').on('click', function() {
        $(this).
        console.log("He-hey!");
      });
    }
  }
  app.init();
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ffffff url('../img/geometry2.png');
  /* Background pattern from Subtle Patterns */
  font-family: 'Coda', cursive;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}


/*
 * Styles for the deck of cards
 */

.deck {
  width: 660px;
  min-height: 680px;
  background: linear-gradient(160deg, #02ccba 0%, #aa7ecd 100%);
  padding: 32px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 12px 15px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 0 3em;
}

.deck .card {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  background: #2e3d49;
  font-size: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5);
}

.deck .card.open {
  transform: rotateY(0);
  background: #02b3e4;
  cursor: default;
}

.deck .card.show {
  font-size: 33px;
}

.deck .card.match {
  cursor: default;
  background: #02ccba;
  font-size: 33px;
}


/*
 * Styles for the Score Panel
 */

.score-panel {
  text-align: left;
  width: 345px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.score-panel .stars {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.score-panel .stars li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.score-panel .restart {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Matching Game</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Matching Game</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="score-panel">
      <ul class="stars">
        <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
      </ul>

      <span class="moves">3</span> Moves

      <div class="restart">
        <input type="button" class="fa fa-repeat" value="Restart"></input>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div class="deck">
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-anchor match"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-anchor match"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-bolt open show"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Поправьте внутри `clickHandlers` - `$(this).`, видимо, код не скопировался.

Comment: @Igor, мне кажется, он спрашивает, что там написать)

Comment: @Qwertiy oops, пардон :(

Comment: @Qwertiy, мне кажется, это "она")

Comment: Хочу узнать, что там написать, потому что console.log  показывает, что процесс идет

Comment: @Crantisz, да :) Не читал ник просто.

Answer (score 2):

Если карточки открываются по классу `open` и `show`, так добавьте его:

```
$('.card').on('click', function(){
 $(this).addClass('open').addClass('show')
});
```

или

```
$('.card').on('click', function(){
 $(this).addClass('open show')
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  const app = {
      cards: [
    //  A list that holds all cards
      {
        name: 'diamond',
        icon: 'fa fa-diamond',
        class: 'card'
      },
      {
        name: 'diamond',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-diamond'
      },
      {
        name: 'plane',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-paper-plane-o'
      },
      {
        name: 'plane',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-paper-plane-o'
      },
      {
        name: 'anchor',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-anchor'
      },
      {
        name: 'anchor',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-anchor'
      },
      {
        name: 'bolt',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-bolt'
      },
      {
        name: 'bolt',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-bolt'
      },
      {
        name: 'cube',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-cube'
      },
      {
        name: 'cube',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-cube'
      },
      {
        name: 'leaf',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-leaf'
      },
      {
        name: 'leaf',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-leaf'
      },
      {
        name: 'bicycle',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-bicycle'
      },
      {
        name: 'bicycle',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-bicycle'
      },
      {
        name: 'bomb',
        class: 'card',
        icon: 'fa fa-bomb'
      },
    ],
      init: function() {
        app.shuffle();
      },

      shuffle: function() {
      let random = 0;
      let temp = 0;
      for(i = 1; i < app.cards.length; i++) {
        random = Math.round(Math.random() * i);
        temp = app.cards[i];
        app.cards[i] = app.cards[random];
        app.cards[random] = temp;
      }
      app.assignCards();
      
    },
      assignCards: function() {
        $('.card').each(function(index){
          $(this).attr('data-card-value', app.cards[index]);
          app.cards[index];
        });
        app.clickHandlers();
      },

      clickHandlers: function(){
      $('.card').on('click', function(){
             $(this).addClass('open').addClass('show')
        console.log("He-hey!");
        }); 
      }
    }
  app.init();
});
```

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: #ffffff url('../img/geometry2.png'); /* Background pattern from Subtle Patterns */
    font-family: 'Coda', cursive;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

/*
 * Styles for the deck of cards
 */

.deck {
    width: 660px;
    min-height: 680px;
    background: linear-gradient(160deg, #02ccba 0%, #aa7ecd 100%);
    padding: 32px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 12px 15px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 0 3em;
}

.deck .card {
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    background: #2e3d49;
    font-size: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 5px 2px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5);
}

.deck .card.open {
    transform: rotateY(0);
    background: #02b3e4;
    cursor: default;
}

.deck .card.show {
    font-size: 33px;
}

.deck .card.match {
    cursor: default;
    background: #02ccba;
    font-size: 33px;
}

/*
 * Styles for the Score Panel
 */

.score-panel {
    text-align: left;
    width: 345px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.score-panel .stars {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.score-panel .stars li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.score-panel .restart {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Matching Game</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Matching Game</h1>
        </header>

        <section class="score-panel">
         <ul class="stars">
          <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
         </ul>

         <span class="moves">3</span> Moves

            <div class="restart">
          <input type="button" class="fa fa-repeat" value="Restart"></input>
         </div>
        </section>

        <div class="deck">
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-anchor match"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-anchor match"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bolt open show"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Они должны открываться при нажатии, а классы я думала добавить в этой строке. Т.е. пользователь нажимает, появляется картинка-иконка, и только потом добавляются классы.

Comment: так классы нужны как раз чтобы показать картинки, а не наоборот. Если вам нужна анимация при смене класса - используйте css-свойство [transition](http://htmlbook.ru/css/transition)

Comment: Это не подойдет, так как в index файле (<i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>) классы с именами fa-diamond и аналогичные содержат в себе уже иконку. По идее при нажатии на карточку должна появляться эта самая иконка, а ее - нет.
Хочу понять, где я могла ошибиться и как поправить так, чтобы эта иконка все-таки появлялась.  CSS  тут слабо поможет

Comment: @AnastasiaPolozova   `font-size: 0;` - уберите и все появится. Вы разверните мой код, он работает